# Nan (перевод в строку)

Tags: c++, node.js

Подскажите, как получить строку из `v8::Local<v8::Value> user = info[0];`, используя Nan, чтобы можно было открыть файл `ifstream ntuser("/home/banger/С/Users/" + user->ToString() + "/ntuser.dat");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение задачи(код уже использовал другой немного), может кому пригодится(получил строку из полученной информации в info, а дальше все понятно:

```
void check(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {

  v8::String::Utf8Value userName(info[0]->ToString());
  std::string path = "/home/banger/С/Users/" + std::string(*userName) + "/ntuser.dat";
  //std::string response = "/home/banger/С/Users/" + name + "/ntuser.dat";
  ifstream ntuser(path);

  if(ntuser.is_open()){
     info.GetReturnValue().Set(true);
  } else {
     info.GetReturnValue().Set(false);
  }
}
```